RuntimeError to obtain ImageNet dataset from torchvision.datasets: ILSVRC2012_devkit_t12.tar.gz is not present in the root directory or is corrupted
Given:
import os
from torchvision.datasets import ImageNet
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
train_dataset = ImageNet(
    root=os.path.expanduser("~/.cache"),
    split='train',
    download=True,
    transform=None
)
test_dataset = ImageNet(
    root=os.path.expanduser("~/.cache"),
    split='val',
    download=True,
    transform=None
)
# then send it to DataLoader...

I obtained the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/farid/WS_Farid/ImACCESS/clip/frontend.py", line 7, in <module>
    train_dataset = ImageNet(
  File "/home/farid/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/imagenet.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.parse_archives()
  File "/home/farid/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/imagenet.py", line 66, in parse_archives
    parse_devkit_archive(self.root)
  File "/home/farid/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/imagenet.py", line 147, in parse_devkit_archive
    _verify_archive(root, file, md5)
  File "/home/farid/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/imagenet.py", line 103, in _verify_archive
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(file, root))
RuntimeError: The archive ILSVRC2012_devkit_t12.tar.gz is not present in the root directory or is corrupted. You need to download it externally and place it in /home/farid/.cache.

It seems that pytorch is not providing an easy access to ImageNet dataset anymore.
Checking ImageNet official website, one should request it with NON freely available emails (it is quite time-consuming since it takes 5 work days to get the response):

Kaggle of course provides a link to the entire dataset (~167GB) for manual downloading and manipulation and HuggingFace only provides the statement:

For full ImageNet dataset presented in official paper, please check the download
section of the main website.

Does anybody any possible workaround to get the easy access to obtain ImageNet dataset?
